# image upload using jquery ajax php mysqli

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

using ajax to upload image url in database but i got error when submit form. I want upload image url im database without page refresh. Error is   GET https://api.ciuvo.com/api/analyze?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F&version=2.1.3&tag=threesixty&uuid=C473346A-075C-48CD-A961-F4B68EFE2C4F 400 (Bad Request)

```
 **html code**
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Image:</label>
<input type="file" name="txtimg">
<input type="submit" value="INSERT IMAGE" name="btnimage">
</form>
<div id="message"></div>


**ajax request**
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
$("#form").on('submit',(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  url: "upload.php",   
  type: "POST",             
  data:  new FormData(this),   
  contentType: false,          
      cache: false,         
  processData:false,        
  success: function(data)     
    {
      $("#message").html(data);     
    }         
 });
 }));
 });
```

php code

```
    <?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$db="test";
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysqli_select_db($con,$db);
if (isset($_FILES["file"]["type"])) {
$dir = "images/";
$imagelocation=$dir.basename($_FILES['txtimg']['name']);
$extension = pathinfo($imagelocation,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if($extension != 'jpg' && $extension != 'png' && $extension != 'jpeg')
{
    echo"plzz upload only jpg,jpeg And png";
}
else
{
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['txtimg']['tmp_name'],$imagelocation) )

    {
        if(mysqli_query($con,"Insert into img (img_url) values($imagelocation')"))
        {
            echo"SUCCESSFULLY";
        }
    }

        else {

            echo"ERROR";

        }
}


}

?>
```

Comment: There are a lot reason, did you check return response in browser network panel in developer mode? May you reach max file size

Comment: yes i got this error in network pannel

Comment: Check response body/header for details. Enable php debug mode and check log files.

Comment: i check html developer mode i dont why iframe in add my ajax request  <iframe src="https://www.ciuvo.com/ciuvo/globalstorage?version=2.1.3" style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px; left: -9999px;"></iframe>

Comment: Because of extension, disable ciuvo extension in your browser.

Comment: thank you so much now its fine but image url not upload in database. You look any error in php file?

Comment: I prefer enable php debug mode and check logs. If there is no error in php log, check web server log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call FormData object inside ajax request,

**html code**

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Image:</label>
<input type="file" name="txtimg">
<input type="submit" value="INSERT IMAGE" name="btnimage">
</form>
<div id="message"></div>


**ajax request**
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {

$("#form").on('submit',(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var fdata = new FormData(this);

$.ajax({
  url: "upload.php",   
  type: "POST",             
  data: fdata,   
  contentType: false,          
      cache: false,         
  processData:false,        
  success: function(data)     
    {
      $("#message").html(data);     
    }         
 });
 }));
 });
```

Comment: when i click on submit button page refresh and didn't find any error and url not store in database.

Comment: php doesn't know what is your request you should have if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {} before you evaluate the file.